# Reversing Django URLs With Extra Options

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a URLconf like below, and `'foo'` and `'bar'` are valid values for `page_slug`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^page/(?P<page_slug>.*)/', 'myapp.views.someview'),
)
```

Then, I could reconstruct the URLs using the below, right?

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('myapp.views.someview', kwargs={'page_slug': 'foo'})
'/page/foo/'
>>> reverse('myapp.views.someview', kwargs={'page_slug': 'bar'})
'/page/bar/'
```

But what if I change my URLconf to this?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo-direct/', 'myapp.views.someview', {'page_slug': 'foo'}),
    (r'^my-bar-page/', 'myapp.views.someview', {'page_slug': 'bar'}),
)
```

I expected this result:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('myapp.views.someview', kwargs={'page_slug': 'foo'})
'/foo-direct/'
>>> reverse('myapp.views.someview', kwargs={'page_slug': 'bar'})
'/my-bar-page/'
```

However, this throws a `NoReverseMatch` exception. I suspect I'm trying to do something impossible. Any suggestions on a saner way to accomplish what I want?

Named URLs aren't an option, since I don't want other apps that link to these to need to know about the specifics of the URL structure (encapsulation and all that).

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Error message?   If so, what?

Comment: It throws a `NoReverseMatch` exception.

Comment: Please update the question with new facts -- don't add the useful information as comments.

Answer (score 21):

You should try naming your urlconfs. Example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^foo-direct/', 'myapp.views.someview', {'page_slug': 'foo'}, name='foo-direct'),
    url(r'^my-bar-page/', 'myapp.views.someview', {'page_slug': 'bar'}, name='bar-page'),
)
```

Then just edit your reverses and you should get it working.

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('foo-direct', kwargs={'page_slug': 'foo'})
'/foo-direct/'
>>> reverse('bar-page', kwargs={'page_slug': 'bar'})
'/my-bar-page/'
```

More info at: [Django Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#id2)

Comment: How exactly does this help with a url conf like in the question: (r'^page/(?P<page_slug>.*)/', 'myapp.views.someview'), ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's what we do.

urls.py has patterns like this

```
url(r'^(?P< datarealm >.*?)/json/someClass/(?P<object_id>.*?)/$', 'json_someClass_resource', ),
```

views.py as reverse calls like this

```
    object = SomeModel.objects.get(...)
    url= reverse('json_someClass_resource', kwargs={'object_id':object.id,'datarealm':object.datarealm.name})
```

Comment: I don't think that helps with the name collision problem.

Comment: I originally downvoted you because of what David said, but it does look like you do actually answer Justin's question. I still think David's answer is the "better" one, but yours is a possibility.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand how this applied to the above on first reading.  I guess it looks like it could work...but only at the cost of putting a reference to a url name in the model level.  If object_1.datarealm.name='foo-direct' this will work, if object_1.datarealm.name='foo', this will not.

Comment: Those aren't url-names -- those are values that plug into the url pattern.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Named urls ought to be an option.  Your case is highlighted in the Django reference:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/?from=olddocs#id2

I'm  not sure the designers left another work-around; they expected named urls to cover it.

May I digress about encapsulation?  Thanks.  There are two main reasons:

1. Abstraction--no one *wants* to see the details
2. Security--no one *should* see the details

As for 1, you can get a decent amount of mileage out of it in python, and Django is an excellent example.  As for 2, it's an interpreted language.  Either you're running it where it's written, or you're shipping off compiled .pyc files.  If that's really what you're doing, then compile the url conf.

Finally, it seems less encapsulated to let other apps know about the functions than the url structure.  But if you really disagree, I think you'll have to implement a more flexible reverse method yourself.

Comment: Agreed; exporting named URLs as an API is just as "encapsulated" as exporting view function names.

Comment: #2 - Security through obscurity? :(

Comment: I think the link is out of date. What section did you want to link to?