# Cannot resolve Django "NoReverseMatch" exception with kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have am unable to get Django to reverse-resolve the following named url -

URLconf entry :

```
url(r'^shotmanager/(?P<shotid>\d+)/$', 'ctac.views.shotManager', {'message': "", 'errors': []}, name = 'shot-manager')
```

HttpResponseRedirect call:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("shot-manager", kwargs={'shotid': id, 'message': s, 'errors': errorList}))
```

I see nothing in the Django docs that suggests I cannot mix kwargs in the url and the dictionary entry in the url.  For some reason, reverse will resolve fine if I only send it "shotid".

I have already visited the following thread

[Reversing Django URLs With Extra Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659832/reversing-django-urls-with-extra-options)

and have studied it.  It is unclear if it was resolved either.

Answer (score 4):

`reverse` returns a URL populated with the values you pass in the args or kwargs. But the URL you are trying to generate hasn't got a space for `message`. Where would it go in the generated URL?

**Edit in response to comment**
If you want to pass messages between page views, the correct way to do it is not via the URL, but by via the session. Django even includes a [messaging framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/messages/) to manage this for you.

Comment: Agreed. And just to further clarify, the dict specified in the url pattern's kwargs is used to specify extra values to be passed to the associated view function. It has no bearing on the URL itself, or how the URL is resolved, matched, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that makes sense - the API doesn't specifically say that the redirect couldn't override the extra variables being passed as well as the variable in the URL.  Is there you guys know of to send data through the message and error variables, the way I have it set up, through a Redirect?  Thanks so much for you responses.

Comment: What I'm saying is I need a form to redirect back to itself (a la the POST-REDIRECT-GET paradigm) so that a refresh doesn't resubmit the form, but do so with a message or error variable populated so I can display it in the form.